# " nodemon: command not found" while I am trying to install using yarn

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, nodemon

I have installed nodemon using yarn but somehow it is showing command not found. I have been trying to get solution but not getting any yet. whenever I use `nodemon` command it shows  `nodemon: command not found`

I have tried installing `yarn global add nodemon` and also `yarn add nodemon`. I had even tried installing dev dependencies.

Whenever I try installing using `npm`it works but not for yarn.
Can anyone help me out of it how can I solve this using `yarn`?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Well, I am using windows 10 Pro

Comment: Are you sure that the path has been configured correctly?

Comment: yes, I have installed from the git bash cli from vscode on the project.

Comment: Version of yarn?

Comment: current version: 1.0.0

Comment: Can you check the yarn has been added to the PATH in your system variables?

Comment: yes, I do regular basis react projects using yarn. I just started to learn backend today. And somehow I am facing this issue. everything installs successfully, so do the nodemon. but whenever I use the command nodemon it shows the error message.

Comment: That means you have installed other modules globally using yarn and it worked well?

Comment: yes, the rest of them are working very well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `yarn nodemon` command in terminal, it will work for yarn install.

example:

```
yarn nodemon index
```